# Public boolean action: missing return statement

Tags: java, return, return-value, return-type

Java gives me error to public boolean action: missing return statement.      How I solve it?

The programme creates 3 buttons Yes, No, Maybe.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class ButtonDemo extends Applet {
     String msg = "Ti piace Java?";
     public void init() {
              Button yes = new Button("Si");
              Button no = new Button("No");
              Button maybe = new Button("Non so");
              setBackground(Color.white);
              add(yes);
              add(no);
              add(maybe);
     }
     public void paint(Graphics g) {
              g.drawString(msg,6,100);
     }
public boolean action(Event evtObj,
                                  Object arg) {
       if (evtObj.target instanceof Button) {
                 if (arg.equals("Si")) {
                            setBackground(Color.green);
                            msg = "I love Java!";
                 }
                 if (arg.equals("No")) {
                            setBackground(Color.red);
                            msg = "Io odio Java!";
                 }
                 if (arg.equals("Non so")) {
                            setBackground(Color.yellow);
                            msg = "Non me ne importa niente!";
                 }
       }
}       
}
```

Comment: `return someBooleanValue;`

Comment: your public boolean action method isn't returning anything for no matter what scenario, yet for each and every possibility, it has to return either true or false

Comment: You have declared the method `action` to return a `boolean`, but aren't returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

Add a return statement at the end of the `action` listener method, like `return true;`.

To start hating Java a bit less, I would recommend some basic tutorial instead of delving right into applets, like [this one](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-java/) :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you answered your own question. There's no return statement in your action method. The boolean after "public" means that you need to return a boolean value. true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, write a return statement(like "return true" or "return false") at the end of action method. Otherwise remove boolean from "public boolean action" and write "public boolean action" if you don't want to return any value from this function.